# AJAX Show/Hide Start/Stop only once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

i have some code in AJAX thats working quite fine (on a beginners perspective). I load an image when AJAX calls being made, but unfortunately its only shown once when the post (through a html select) is made initially on first time, never after...

Shortened code:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#loading").show();
});

$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("#loading").hide();
});

function queryDates() {
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/dates',
        data: {index:$('#collections-select option:selected').val()},
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            //alert(data.join(' '));
            generateSelectDates(data);
        })
    }
```

The image is not shown when i change the select although i can see an AJAX (re)post in console.

May someone lend a hand, please.

Thanks...

Comment: I personally haven't used the `ajaxStart` event, however [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) says *"Register a handler to be called when the **first** Ajax request begins."*

Comment: I believe you want the [`ajaxSend`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/) and [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) events as opposed to `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop`.

Comment: I changed my code to use ajaxSend and ajaxComplete but unfortunately that has no effect to my issue.....same behaviour.